# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory with ABSOLUTE file path

Tags: python, csv

I have read through several other questions about this topic, but none seem to work.

**Here's my code:**

```
fileIN_csv = "C:/OpenWeatherMap_Stockholm_bulk_5years.csv"
with open(fileIN_csv) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimeter=',')
```

And here is proof of the file's path:
**[File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy8dj.png)**

And here is the specific error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:/OpenWeatherMap_Stockholm_bulk_5years.csv'
```

Comment: `r'C:\OpenWeatherMap_Stockholm_bulk_5years.csv'`?

Comment: @Stael `C:\\OpenWeatherMap_Stockholm_bulk_5years.csv`

Comment: yeah, i meant that he had the wrong path and was changing my comment when you caught me :P

Comment: @Stael Python allows `/` on Windows at least in recent versions.

Comment: Are you able to open some other file? Or the same file from different location?

Comment: @Stael that did not work. Thanks though! Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelO. That change didn't help either. Thanks! Any other suggestions?

Comment: @K.Kirsz I moved the csv file to a different location and it still says the same error.

Comment: This must be something wrong with the file itself. Maybe there is some weird character in the name or something. Try renaming it or tweaking the file attributes/permissions.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you ever get the file to load you should check the spelling on `delimiter`.

Comment: @Stael thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try removing the .csv bit at the end. when I request files I leave the extension off and it works.

Comment: I tried that, and it did not work either. Thanks! Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path('C:/OpenWeatherMap_Stockholm_bulk_5years.csv')
print(file_path, file_path.exists())
```

say?

Comment: It says false. Why would that path not exist when that is where the file is located?

Comment: do you find the file in `Path('C:/').glob('*')`

Comment: @jeffgiff Maybe you are using python in Cygwin?

Comment: @MichaelO. I do not believe so. Is there a way to check?

Comment: @K.Kirsz it gives me: ['C', 'E']